# Regular expression to insert quotation marks around contents of 2nd and 3rd fields in comma-delimited data

Tags: regex

I need to do a find and replace in Notepad++ of

> Err.Number, canBeAnything, canBeAnything, Err.Description

(where canBeAnything is just what it says)
with

> Err.Number, "canBeAnything", "canBeAnything", Err.Description

(basically, put quotes around canBeAnything)
I got as far as the find

> Err.Number, .+, .+, Err.Description

But I'm stuck on the replace. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add groups to your regex:

Err.Number, (.+), (.+), Err.Description

and then reference then my location in your replace:

replace with

Err.Number, "\1", "\2", Err.Description

Answer (score 1):

Your match is doing more work than it needs to.

```
Err.Number,([^,]+),([^,]+),Err.Description
```

This matches "Err.Number", a comma, anything that's not a comma up to.., a comma, anything that's not a comma up to.., a comma, and "Err.Description".

Answer (score 1):

May be you should use non-greedy qualifiers:

```
Err.Number, .+?, .+?, Err.Description
```